# How to use shell to filter a file by lines?

Tags: shell

I hava a log file like bellow:

```
5082 //open_api/user/get_user_info
5074 /user/get_user_idCard_info?passportId=YRD1412538757&viewSource=02
5029 /user/getuserinfo?passportId=YRD1412538757
4706 /user/getuserinfo?passportId=YRD1507000030516
4611 /user/get_user_idCard_info?passportId=YRD1507000030516&viewSource=02
4040 /salesloan/update_draw_bank
```

The output should be like:

```
5082 //open_api/user/get_user_info
9685 /user/get_user_idCard_info
9735 /user/getuserinfo
4040 /salesloan/update_draw_bank
```

The number before each line is the number this url is called. Now I want to count how many times each url(without params for get http request)is requested, for example as above I only want to count the times the '/repay/query_need_repay_data.action' url was called. Now I am using java to filter and process the lines, but for a 200M bytes file it already took 4 hours and still working, I want to know in which way could I get the work done quickly?

Java codes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String source = "/Users/leo/logs/p2pservice/access/a2.output";
        String target = "/Users/leo/logs/p2pservice/access/targetUrls";
        File targetFile = new File(target);
        String splinter = "\\?";

        List<String> strings = Files.readLines(new File(source), Charsets.UTF_8);
        for (String string : strings) {
            if (string.contains("?")) {
                String[] split = string.split(splinter);
               Files.append(string.split(splinter)[0].toString() + "\n", targetFile, Charsets.UTF_8);
            } else {
                Files.append(string + "\n", targetFile, Charsets.UTF_8);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For above lines , it should be like 122333 /repay/query_need_repay_data.action

Comment: why 122333? I count around 14K if I sum the first columns.

Comment: Yes you are right , should be 14, I didn't count.Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why don't you try to speed up your Java app instead?

Comment: But do all the lines contain the same basic url query_need_repay_data.action? Try to provide a [mcve] if you want people to understand what is the issue here.

Comment: I think there might be better ways. I tried to process the file using guava.

Comment: This can be done just as quickly in Java as in a shell script. Which would you rather have? It's not the language, it's your code. Your Java program has a couple of really huge inefficiencies (not to mention, it doesn't even count anything).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'[ ?]' '{a[$2]+=$1} END{for(k in a) print a[k], k}' file

14341 /repay/query_need_repay_data.action
```